# Linux - Get a line from one file and corresponding line from a second file and pass into cp command

Tags: linux, bash, copy

I have two .txt files.

'target.txt' is a list of target files 
'destination.txt' is a list of (on corresponding lines) of destinations.

I'd like to create a command that does the following:

```
  cp [line 1 from target.txt] [line 1 from destination.txt]
```

For each line of the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
paste target.txt destination.txt | sed -e 's/^/cp /' > cp.cmds
```

Then, after inspecting `cp.cmds` for correctness, you can just run it as a shell script.

```
sh cp.cmds
```

Comment: ! I think you answered my last question as well. Really brilliant method here. Simple and fast. Beautiful work! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `paste` command merges two files by concatenating corresponding lines.

```
paste target.txt destination.txt | while read target dest; do
    cp $target $dest
done
```

This will not work if any of the filenames contain spaces, though. If that's a requirement, I would use `awk` to read the first file into an array, then when reading the second file print a `cp` command with the corresponding lines and quotes around them, and pipe this to `sh` to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

To handle whitespace in the filenames:

```
paste -d\\n target.txt destination.txt | xargs -d\\n -n2 -x cp
```

- `paste -d\\n` interleaves lines of the argument files
- `xargs -d\\n -n2` reads two complete lines at a time and applies them as two arguments at the end of the command line. The `-d` flag disables all special processing of quotes, apostrophes and backslashes in the input lines, as well as the eof character (by default _).

The `-d` command-line options to `xargs` is a GNU extension. If you are stuck with a Posix standard `xargs`, you can use the following alternative, courtesy of the [Open Group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) (see example 2, near the end of the page):

```
paste -d\\n target.txt destination.txt |
sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]/\\&/g' |
xargs -E "" -n 2 -x cp
```

- The `sed` command backslash-escapes every non-alphanumeric character
- `xargs -E ""` disables the end-of-file character handling.